# Connecting Audio interface to amp head to use 4x12 Cabinet as a monitor?

Tags: guitar

Forgive me if this is a stupid question but I want to make use of my old 6505 head and cab as a dedicated guitar monitor.

In theory I'd like to Guitar > AI > Bias FX2 > AI line out > input head(or effects loop?) > Cab

Thoughts? Suggestions?
I don't really want to expand my pedal board any further

Answer (score 4):

In my personal experience (read: for my personal taste) *amp cabinet* sims in the Bias FX2 will sound bad fed into a guitar amp: they are better targeted to a full-range audio system. The pedal effects (etc) will otherwise sound fine. You will want to adjust your interface output levels such that with no effects defined, the audio levels are the same with the interface in bypass mode (disabled).

I only play at home for personal gratification and was using only PC-based sims but have recently gone to a simplified pedal setup with the interface between a compressor and a tube-screamer type device. the hard part about a mixed environment like this is that *all* the effect on the interface are inserted into the chain as a block.

If you are only going to use the Bias (no physical pedals), you will want to use what is called a [re-amp device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re-amp#Electronic_interfacing) between the "AI-out" and the amp-head in for impedance reasons. I used a DIY kit called "line2amp," but there are several commercial options. I think you will need the reamp device if you output to another pedal also (I do this because I think it sounds better), but I do not know if it is required.

If you are going to use this outside of a DAW playback setup (which has track envelopes), you will probably want a midi expression pedal (or several). Don't know if Bias supports MIDI input, but if it does, you will want one for wah or volume. Most audio hosts will allow you to tag a midi input to *any* possible pedal parameter and often several at once. I use a usb MIDI 3-button pedal and a midi expression pedal.

Comment: For reference, my chain is: guitar > fuzz > compressor > interface {PC MAGIC} > re-amp box > tube pedal > 50 watt amp set (mostly) clean.